# Is there a reliable way to obtain a dragon to ride?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons

I am very interested in finding a way to ride a Dragon in my friends 5E campaign. She has stated there will be lots of dragons. I assume I will need to find a wrymling and bind to it. Anyone have any classic or creative ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPG Stackexchange. In case you didn't do it already, the [Tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) helps to get a hold of what the site is about. As per your question, it seems like a shopping list question, when you ask about ideas and suggestions. There might be hundreds of them and as it stands, it does not fit the Stackexchange format. You might want to ask about published rules for dragon riding or maybe adventures where dragon riding is featured, but "classic or creative ideas" are better suited to a forum.

Comment: If you look [at this thread on our Meta forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go), you will find a number of good forums where the question as asked will receive the kind of brain storming you seek.  Beyond that, how much discussion on this matter, you riding a dragon, have you had with your DM?  In any game, something like that tends to have a lot of DM/GM input or control.

Comment: Hmm there is actually information about dragons in the Monster Manual that induce that having/owning a dragon mount would be highly unlikely.

Comment: @Yotus Not all players have a Monster Manual.  It can be argued that it is a "DM resource" in a general sense.

Comment: [Possibly related question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68917/would-animal-handling-apply-when-interacting-with-a-young-dragon?rq=1) having to do with who might dominate a human/dragon relationship.