# Is it a good act to change a bad guy to being a werebear?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, alignment

Is it a good act to change a bad guy into a werebear?

Since the alignment of a werebear is always lawful good, this would convert the bad guys.

But... is it a good act to ignore his intention to forcefully make it lawful good?

Comment: Questions about "what alignment is this act?" are primarily opinion based, so I'm closing this. See meta: [Are questions about alignment on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5358/1204)

Comment: For a discussion prompt type question, you might be interested [in our curated list of discussion forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566) that might fit your needs better.

Comment: MM p.7: "The alignment specified in a monster's stat block is the default. Feel free to depart from it...." Werebears aren't *always* LG, in other words. (From a question on [forcing alignment changes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74401/23970).)