Forced alignment changing effects in official published sources
What alignment changing effects are there (in official published sources)?

A good start seems to be in: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/74407/45342 where the focus is on changing the alignment to good. But I don't think it's complete. (For example it leaves out the Balance card from the Deck of many things.)

Yes I read all answers in the question I linked. That question was clearly not the same. It focused on raising a creature and therefore answers clearly went into the direction of "The alignment specified in a monster's stat block is the default." and "Alignment is descriptive you can change it  by teaching it." This is clearly a different question about mechanics that explicitly change alignment. There was never an attempt asked in the question or made in an answer to list all alignment changing effects. And such an answer would be inappropriate for that question as the OP there is only interested in changes from evil into good.

What research have you done regarding what is in the book, and in particular the DMG?

Did you read all the answers to that question? The Balance card was included in an answer provided seven years ago. People quite carefully listed all sorts of alignment changing effects, even ones that would require changing the dragon's type before changing their alignment; if it's not complete, new answers can still go there.

@ShadowRanger, yes see my edit repeated here for clarity "Yes I read all answers in the question I linked. That question was clearly not the same. It focused on raising a creature and therefore answers clearly went into the direction of "The alignment specified in a monster's stat block is the default." and "Alignment is descriptive you can change it by teaching it." This is clearly a different question about mechanics that explicitly change alignment."

cont'ed... There was never an attempt asked in the question or made in an answer to list all alignment changing effects. And such an answer would be inappropriate for that question as the OP there is only interested in changes from evil into good.

@Kvothe: The OP asked for way to make them "less evil", not necessarily good. And the answers fully covered all ways to forcibly change alignment.

To be duplicates, questions need to be identical, not just those questions' answers. Otherwise, every question to which the answer is "yes" would be a duplicate. Accordingly, I'm voting to reopen this question.

Pervasive Evil is also mentioned in the Descent into Avernus campaign. While I don't believe that it's relevant to the linked question, it should definitely be included in any answer to this question
